# Moving postgresql data folder on Mint 19.1

Tags: linux-mint, postgresql

I want to move my data folder from my SSD do HDD on my Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon.

I have install postgresql from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads version Linux x86-64 10.7. I have found this article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-18-04 and tried to follow, but I am stuck.

I have my data directory here: /opt/PostgreSQL/10/data (from psql -> SHOW data_directory) and I have my postgresql.conf in this data directory as well (/opt/PostgreSQL/10/data/postgresql.conf). I can move my data directory, but I would move conf file as well. I just cannot see, how postgresql would know new configuration if this configuration is in new location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, unfortunately I was not able to achieve what I want with pgAdmin4 installation.
I have installed postgresql: sudo apt install postgresql-10
After that I have my postgresql.conf here: /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf

I have done what is in this tutorial (same as in question):
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-18-04

But then I got stuck again with problem answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653690/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-5432-error

So I am checking my log file postgresql-10-main.log and I see this:
pgctl: could not access directory "/my/new/datadir/postgresql/10/main": Permission denied

I have added owner like this: sudo chown -R postgres /my/new/data_dir/
and added permissions like this: sudo chmod -R o=rwx /my/new/data_dir/

And after that I got really good error message again in my log file postgresql-10-main.log that said, that "/my/new/datadir/postgresql/10/main" directory has to have 0700 permissions.

After that, it finally works.